# mysql + ruby = nightmare

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, macports

Ok, I'm done.
I can't understand why I got this error with:

```
rake features
```

It cant' be I can't connect to mysql cause the:

```
rake db:migrate
```

works perfectly.

I keep having this error:

```
rake features --trace
(in /Users/myname/Projects/rails_app)
** Invoke features (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
rake aborted!
closed stream
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:1032:in `sync='
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:1032:in `write'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:1092:in `finalizer'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:578:in `call'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:578:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mysql.rb:578:in `free'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:438:in `tables'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:24:in `table_exists?'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:106:in `create_table'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:473:in `create_table'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `send'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:352:in `method_missing'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:293:in `measure'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:328:in `say_with_time'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:348:in `method_missing'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/db/schema.rb:38
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema.rb:43:in `instance_eval'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/schema.rb:43:in `define'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/db/schema.rb:12
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/databases.rake:259
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/databases.rake:304
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/Projects/rails_app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/databases.rake:378
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/myname/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

My machine:
Mac OS X 10.5.8
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [universal-darwin9.0]
Rails 2.3.4
mysql (2.8.1) [rubygem]
Mysql path: /opt/local/lib/mysql5 [installed via macport]

Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 because the title made me laugh

Comment: Title makes the question unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Save your DBs and reinstall mysql. Follow http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/ Made all my problems go away.

Comment: Ciao Bello!
I'm on Mac OS X 10.5, not Snow Leopard.

Comment: I think the answer is probably still correct. There are older hivelogic articles. You're suffering from the 'closed stream' problem which is really common. MySQL on OS X is a pain and there's not much you can do about it other than following the guidance of a wiser OS X hacker :P

Comment: Dude, upgrade to the white cat asap.

Answer (score 0):

I have to theories about your problem, but no reason to suspect either is really your cause, but they're quick checks.

1. You haven't properly defined the testing database in `config/databases.yml`
2. The mysql user that is attempting to build this database lacks the permission to do so.

Comment: 1. yes
2. it's root and no password. It works when I connect directly to mysql and rake db:migrate is working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to the database in question with the credentials in question (all the stuff in database.yml)?

"mysql -u your_user -p" from the command line?

When you installed the mysql gem did it properly build the native extensions?
What happens when you gem install mysql --force  (to re-install it)?  Does it look happy?

Have you ever done this before? Is the problem as likely to be a lack of experience with rails/mysql or both?  Or is this old hat and you just can't figure it out this time?

If the former, the tutorial in the pragramatic agile web development with rails is quite good (as is the rest of the book).

Hope something there helps.

Comment: 1. YES
sudo /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql -u root -p ""
Password: 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL connection id is 1 Server version: 5.1.41 Source distribution Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement. 
mysql>

Comment: 2. I just got a long list of errors when it comes to "Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.8.1..." like:
"No definition for next_result
No definition for field_name
No definition for field_table"

Comment: Errors in rdoc usually don't mean anything much. Certainly they don't screw up your gem.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell the output of:

rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test

to be sure that an existing database named _test is configured and working under config/database.yml

Comment: 1. This is what I get if with "rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test"  http://pastie.org/722893 the weird thing is I do have that gem, as you can see http://pastie.org/722895
2. The settings in database.yml are correct, I could create all the tables in db_test as you can see http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/9629/picture7c.png

Comment: edit config/environments/test.rb and uncomment the last lines:

config.gem "rspec", :lib => 'spec'
config.gem "rspec-rails", :lib => 'spec/rails'
config.gem "cucumber"

Let me know what happens, please.

Comment: This is how my "config/environments/test.rb" look like http://pastie.org/723646 , they are already uncommented.

Comment: Is it possible rake can't just find those gems?

This is my >gem list (http://pastie.org/723688) <br> but this is what I see inside /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems (http://pastie.org/723692) rspec and rspec-rails aren't there...